# What is the purpose of a placeholder type in a trailing-return-type?

Tags: c++, language-lawyer

According to [[dcl.fct]/2](http://eel.is/c++draft/dcl.fct#2) the snippet below is legal. [GCC and clang compile and execute the code](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/7dfd34f26913f786),

```
#include <iostream>
int i = -1;
auto f()->auto&& { return i; }
int main(){
    f() = 2;
    std::cout << i << '\n';
}
```

printing

```
2
```

But what is the purpose of allowing this in C++?

In the example above, one could get the same result just by replacing the trailing-return-type with `int&`. In other words, I'm looking for an example where the trailing-return-type containing a placeholder type would be meaningful.

Comment: If it was forbidden, then one would ask "why is it forbidden?".

Comment: To allow you to write functions like `f()` in the above code?

Comment: why shouldnt it be allowed? i have to admit, i really dont get it

Comment: @user463035818 In the example above, one could get the same result just by replacing the trailing-return-type with `int&`. In other words, I'm looking for an example where the trailing-return-type containing a placeholder type would be meaningful.

Comment: ah ok, i am not used to lots of `auto` so one more didnt surprise me too much

Comment: @WaldB: just because it doesn't have a real usage (?), it should not be forbidden. It would make the language inconsistent.

Comment: I don't think language-lawyer tag is appropriate here, this question is asking about rationale, not about the wording of the standard

Comment: In `auto f(T& t)->auto&& { return t.foo; }` what should the second `auto` be replaced with?

Comment: Is `auto&&` a typo and should be `auto&` instead? Outside of `std::move()`, is returning an rvalue reference from a function worthwhile to do?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can find the answer in the revision [N3582](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2013/n3582.html) (2013-03-15)<sup>1</sup> to the original proposal for `auto`:

> **`auto` in *trailing-return-type***
>
> This proposal initially did not allow auto in a *trailing-return-type*, but since then it was pointed out that putting it there is the only way to specify that a lambda returns by a deduced reference type:
>
> ```
> []()->auto& { return f(); }
> ```

(Remember that not only functions but also lambdas can have a *trailing-return-type*)

Hence [[dcl.spec.auto]/2](https://timsong-cpp.github.io/cppwp/n3337/dcl.spec.auto#2):

> The `auto` *type-specifier* may appear with a function declarator with a *trailing-return-type* ([dcl.fct]) in any context where such a declarator is valid.

---

<sup>1</sup> Note: N3582 has been superseded by [N3638](https://isocpp.org/files/papers/N3638.html) before it was actually adopted.

Comment: In [\[dcl.spec.auto\]/3](http://eel.is/c++draft/dcl.spec.auto#3) we have the phrase: `Otherwise, the function declaration shall declare a function.`. What is the point of this assertion, given that the function declaration also declares a function in the first case, i.e., when the function declarator includes a  trailing-return-type? Could you clarify this?

Comment: That's a very weird way to say `auto` is not allowed in e.g. `void f(auto (*)());`. See [core issue 1892](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/cwg_defects.html#1892). (And it's not *declaration* but *declarator*)

Answer (score 6):

You can make an argument about consistency: you can stick other types as trailing return types, why not placeholders?

```
auto f() -> int&  { return i; }
auto f() -> auto& { return i; }
```

You can make an argument about utility: the return type for lambdas looks like a trailing return type and has no other place to put a placeholder type, so you have to allow it for lambdas anyway, so might as well allow it for functions?

```
auto f = []() -> int&  { return i; };
auto f = []() -> auto& { return i; };
```

You can make an argument about code formatting. The trailing return type allows for consistent way to declare functions that always works for all cases, so just lining it up:

```
auto g(auto x)     -> decltype(f(x)) { ... } // using trailing for parameter
auto Cls::member() -> type { ... }  // using trailing for scope (to find Cls::type)
auto h(auto x)     -> auto& { ... }  // using trailing for formatting
```

There might be other arguments. But in short, it's easy to allow and clearly has merit.

Comment: Could you explain what do you mean by `auto g(auto x)     -> decltype(f(x)) { ... } // using trailing for argument`. That doesn't make much sense to me.

Comment: @WaldB The return type is based on the parameter (wrote argument, meant parameter), `x`, so I need to put it in the trailing position

Comment: I'm not familiar with using `auto` as a parameter-type. Could you tell me the quote in the standard supporting this?

Comment: @WaldB The parameter type really doesn't matter, I used `auto` as shorthand. Imagine a template parameter or whatever. Although C++20 will allow `auto` as well.